# How to pass the interactive grid select value to the modal dialog page

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid on parent page and from the parent page the modal dialog page is opened. What is the best way to transfer the grid selected value id to the modal dialog page? Do I set up a global variable?

Comment: Good question, first I would try to simply grab the selected record using parent.apex.region("myid").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").view$.grid("getSelectedRecords")  . Is there any problem in doing this?

Comment: I am already doing that and there is no problem with that. Is there a way I can assign this value to a hidden page variable?

Comment: The report is on a parent page and you need to send the value of some row to a item on a modal page. How do you open the modal page or how do you create the link to the modal page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I added hidden field on the page and stored selected value in there. I added another hidden field on modal dialog page and then set it to the value of the first hidden field. It is easily done on the parent page when specifying which page is to be opened in a modal dialog